# Problem parse integer within JSON response

Tags: string, json, integer, response

I have following JSON response string

```
 {"firstname":"a","lastname":"a","jobtitle":"software developer","companyname":"abc","mobileno":9461438988}
```

i cant get the string value for 'mobileno' field
This is how i read the 'mobileno' field

```
self.dispPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[parsedProfileData valueForKey:@"mobileno"]];
```

the string here becomes some garbage value '2147483647' when i NSLog it

Comment: That JSON is wrong.  Phone numbers are strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a phone number is not an integer. Phone numbers may start with significant 0s or `+`. For example, in Germany `00..` is international, `0` national, and any other digit regional.

The returned value is the highest possible 31 bit number. Since your JSON encoder decodes to signed 32bit ints, this is the best value it can give you.

To solve this problem, format phone numbers as strings in the original.

Answer (score 0):

The number `9,461,438,988` cannot be stored in a 32-bit value, so it's being truncated to fit.

You should store your phone numbers as the strings they are (just like ZIP codes).

In general, anything that you don't want to do arithmetic or numeric comparison on (`<` or `>`) is a string, not a number.

Comment: Nope, it's not truncated - that would result in 871504396.

Comment: I meant that the value is being truncated, not that the bits are being truncated.